# Excel 2016 and Office 365 custom document property

Tags: excel-interop, office365api, office-js

I have an Excel XLL which uses Excel Interop and I use customDocumentProperties to store some settings for the workbook. The C# code looks like:

```
var customDocumentProperties = Workbook.CustomDocumentProperties;
customDocumentProperties.Add("MyData", false, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "mysettings");
```

Now I am trying to create an Office add-in (excel task-pane) with Office.js and the equivalent way to store custom data is using Office.context.document.settings. So javascript code looks something like:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("MyData", "mysettings");
```

However, these two methods are incompatible. ie. if I set the property with the the XLL, I can not read it with the Office add-in and vice versa.

Is there anyway to create compatible custom document properties that can be used in both `Excel 2016` (through `xll` `c# or vba`) and Office 365 Excel?

Thanks in advance,
Jon

Comment: Did you figure out a way to set custom properties in Office 365?

Comment: The second method above (Office.context.document.settings.set) works in Office 365 using Office.js. It just isn't compatible with Excel 2016 (method #1 which is the older method).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not currently possible.  You may be able to inspect the OOXML format of the Word document to figure out where the Office add-in settings live, but there's no official path.

We do have adding custom document properties / custom XML parts on our backlog...

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Ok. Thought there might be a way to read/write the custom.xml embedded in the .xlsx. Looks a bit messy. For now I've just "shared" it in some cells in the spreadsheet.